# How to get create time of a folder in QT on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Online search only suggests `QFileInfo` and `QDir`, but there is nothing about folder create time in the documentation of these two.

Is there a straightforward way to get the create time of a folder as `QDateTime` on Windows?

(C++ and Windows API is really like hell for beginners so it's better to avoid them when possible)

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfileinfo.html#birthTime

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks. BTW it is created() for QT5.6